# Anaconda installation fails due to post install scripts Win 2 Error

Tags: python, anaconda, failed-installation

I am trying to reinstall anaconda 64 bit on Windows 7 to use Python 3.6 and the installations works right till the end but it fails executing the post install script with following error.

[image]

However, if I check the `Lib` folder in the `Anaconda3` folder, I see the files `_nsis.py` and `subprocess.py` which the installer says are missing.
Ignoring the error results in no Anaconda navigator in the start menu but the Anaconda prompt is available for some reason.

I tried installing Miniconda too but am facing the same issue. Below is the error snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by installing an archived version of Anaconda rather than the latest one available. Still not sure why the latest version won't install successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can install directly from command prompt or terminal.
I too was facing the same problem but then it get resolve by using pip. Make sure that you upgrade your pip version before installing jyupter notebook/ anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

I identified the reason behind the problem from this [github issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/8856), which is summarized as follows:

> subprocess.py is trying to create the process to run post_install.bat from the command line interpreter (cmd.exe). In order to execute the command, the program has to find the full path of cmd.exe from the system variable called ComSpec. Anaconda3 will fail if the value of ComSpec is wrong.

In my case, I did the following to solve the problem:

1. I erased the existing value of ComSpec in environmental variables of advanced system settings, set it to C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe and restarted my pc.
2. I deleted the Anaconda3 folder from the ProgramData folder in C:\ (ProgramData folder is generally hidden, so change the folder options to show the hidden folders) and then started the installation again.